# Adding a column with type Boolean in button click

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to make a program that whenever a button is clicked, it adds a column with a boolean type. I was guessing that calling the `columnTypes` variable inside the `ActionEvent` of the button that adds column would be valid but it turns out it is not. Is there a way that whenever I add a column to the table, it would automatically be set as a Boolean type?

```
        scrollPane.setViewportView(mainTable);
        mainTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        mainTable.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
        mainTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
                {null, null},
            },
            new String[] {
                "Name", "New column"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] columnTypes = new Class[] {
                String.class, Boolean.class
            };
            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return columnTypes[columnIndex];
            }
        });
        mainPanel.add(addStuBTN);
        
        JButton addDayBTN = new JButton("Add Day");
        addDayBTN.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                DefaultTableModel mdl = (DefaultTableModel)mainTable.getModel();
                
                mdl.addColumn("Day "+(i+1));
                columnTypes[i] = Boolean.class;
                i++;
                }
        });

        addDayBTN.setBounds(10, 387, 113, 23);
        mainPanel.add(addDayBTN);
```

I am sorry if I may have been using the wrong terminologies. I am still a beginner in Java.

Comment: What about, instead of *return columnTypes[columnIndex];* `return columnIndex >= 1 Boolean.class : String.class;`?

Comment: It says syntax error

Comment: Small typo in g00se’s suggestion, but it’s definitely a good solution: `return columnIndex >= 1 ? Boolean.class : String.class;` (note the `?` after the number 1)

Comment: Thank you sirs for the help. I will also take cliff2310's advice in regarding in asking questions in this site. I am sorry for any imperfections in my question.